# What's the earliest a planet could have been formed?

Tags: planets

From what I know the Earth is ~4 billion years old and the universe is ~14 billion years old.

Are there factors that prevented the Earth from forming for that first ~10 billion years?

Perhaps planets that formed closer to the center of the universe/big bang could have formed earlier?

So in essence I'm asking what is the earliest that a planet could have formed and what are the factors/scenario/circumstances for this to happen?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate of, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95766/25301

Comment: "closer to the center of the universe"???!!?!!!?

Comment: To clarify the comment by  @WillO [the universe does not have a center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) (which is a difficult concept, I admit).